# Selecting certain numbers based on corresponding numbers of other column in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I am a newcomer struggling with writing a code in MatLab which is extremely useful for my research. I have csv files with many columns, but interested in only two of them, say columns X and Y, all numbers. What I need to do is picking certain number from X column having approximate corresponding number in Y column. For example, picking a number in X column that has closest-to-54 corresponding Y. Can I do it with MatLab? 
I appreciate any help.

Comment: What's `closest-to-54 corresponding Y`? Could you provide a small input-output combination to explain your case a bit better? That is assume some X, some Y and the output that you are expecting.

Comment: My X in unknown and I want to select it based my Y, but I don't know the exact Y number. For example, I want my Y to be nearest to 54 and the actual number in my datasheet is 54.001. I need to pick the X that correspond to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have your matrix `data` like this:

```
data =

    0.6293   -2.5788   -0.9027   53.0100   -0.7203
    0.3602    2.0267    0.2537   54.5300   -0.0149
    0.0870   -0.7028    1.2209   54.6034    0.5088
   -1.1552    1.5505    0.3589   54.0044    1.1467
    1.7230   -0.5437    0.1975   56.3978   -0.5802
    1.9416    0.7137    0.2764   55.0810   -0.2298
    0.4837   -0.1987    0.8526   53.6421   -0.4461
   -0.1257    1.7165   -0.8384   53.7798    1.3852
    0.6433    0.6902   -1.1979   53.9323   -1.2776
    1.6593   -0.5343   -1.3725   52.8364   -0.0738
```

And you want to find the value on column `X = 2` where the value on the same row, on column `Y = 4`, is closest to 54. You could do it like this:

```
X = 2; % Index of the column to retrieve the value from
Y = 4; % Index of the column to find the value nearest to 54

[~,idx] = min(abs(data(:,Y) - 54))
data(idx,X)
```

Which would give you this:

```
ans =

    1.5505
```

What it's doing is taking the absolute difference between column `Y` and 54 and retrieving the index of the row of the element with minimum difference. Then, this index is used to retrieve the value of that line, on column `X`.

Comment: When I enter X = 2; it only gives a one by one matrix with specified number (2), instead of picking the column. Why is that?

Comment: I don't know, it works here on that data. How exactly is your data represented? A matrix? A cell array?

Comment: The variable `data` was just an example, replace it by your real variable. Also, I'm assuming it's a MxN matrix (not a cell array or anything else).

Comment: That's great. Worked. Thanks. I used to run each line individually, but this time i copied them altogether and pressed enter once...